# Drools rules with boolean variable

Tags: drools

I want to declare a boolean variable in my drl file and wants to write a rule based on the value of that variable. I am not able to find any good example for this.

I tried like:

```
declare Flag
    flag: Boolean
end
```

In one of the rule, I am modifying like:

```
  flag = Boolean.TRUE;
```

and my rule is:

```
rule "<210> Determine flag"
    when
        Flag(flag == true)
    ...
end
```

But it is giving me error as flag cannot be resolved.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot declare variables in the usual way as (I think) you are trying to do. Please read the Drools documentation and distinguish *binding variables*, *global variables*, *facts* and their fields and right hand side local variables (as within a static Java method).

To see how `declare` with a boolean field works, use the following DRL code:

```
declare Flag
  flag: Boolean
end

rule "hoist a Flag"
when
    not Flag()
then
    insert( new Flag( true ) );
end

rule "a true Flag"
when
    Flag( flag )
then
    System.out.println( "The Flag.flag is true." );
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
rule "Test"
   when
      a: TestClass( getFlag())
   then
      //some action
end
```

Also see this answer: [Drools Rule - writing rule against boolean field, name starting with "is"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18598431/drools-rule-writing-rule-against-boolean-field-name-starting-with-is)